# Why does this code compile? cout < "tt";

Tags: c++, stl, cout, ostream

`cout` is object of class `ostream`, and `ostream` is typedef of `basic_ostream`:

```
extern ostream cout;

typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream;

template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
  class basic_ostream;
```

but none of these classes has `operator<`

So I can't understand why this code compiles without any errors:

```
std::cout < "aaa";
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool - and judging by it compiling, it's using the `void *` one, so it's triggering undefined behaviour since the pointers are not related.

Comment: @omid Just so you understand the comment above, you are using "<" which means test for less than' rather than "<<" which is stream out.

Comment: @chris I'm using c++11 . why it use void* ?

Comment: @omid, AFAIK, newer versions of libc++ made the switch and nothing else has yet. I could be wrong, but what's for sure is that your library hasn't.

Comment: BTW `std::ostream` is not an object of `std::basic_ostream`, it's a `typedef` for `std::basic_ostream<char>`, a narrow character output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ language operator `<` makes the compiler to consider a built-in candidate function of the form

```
bool operator<(T, T);
```

for every possible pointer type `T`. In particular, that means that there's such a function for `void *` type. This is the function that is applicable in your case. String literal is implicitly convertible to `void *` and `std::cout` is also implicitly convertible to `void *`.

You can reproduce the same behavior with the following minimalist example

```
struct X {
  operator void *() { return 0; }
};

int main() {
  X() < "";
}
```

The above would apply to C++03. I'm not sure why it compiles in C+11 tough (assuming it does), since in C++11 stream conversion to `void *` was replaced with *explicit* conversion to `bool`.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's just standard library implementations catching up.